# How to get expiration time from setcookie()?

Tags: php, setcookie

I have a cookie, which is working with ssl only:

```
$data = $users->customer->getUsernames();
$data = join(",", $data);
setcookie('test_cookie', $data, time()+3600, '/root/en/server/', 
          'server.test.com', true);
```

Now, how can i get time of this cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookie contents sent in the HTTP request to your server only includes the variables/values that you set in the cookie, not the expiration time.  If you want, you can "pad" the cookie value to **include** the expiration time each time you set it.